# Search for parse errors in logstash/grok

Tags: logstash, kibana, grok, kibana-4

I´m using the elk stack to analyze log data and have to handle large volumes of log data.
It looks like all the logs can be parsed with logstash/grok.

Is there a way to search with kibana for loglines that couldn´t be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grok{} fails to match a one of the patterns that you've provided, it will set a tag called "_grokparsefailure".  You can search for this: tags:_grokparsefailure

If you have multiple grok{} filters, it's recommended to use the tag_on_failure parameter to set a different tag for each grok, so you can more quickly identify the stanza that is causing the problem.